# Periodic points of $\sin(x)$ on $(-1,1)$

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, fixed-points

Let $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow (-1,1):$
$$f(x)=\sin(x)$$
Find all the **periodic points** of $f(x)$. 
Note: a point $p$ is called periodic if $\exists n\in\mathbb N: f^n(p)=\underbrace{f\circ f\circ f\circ \dots \circ f}_{ \text{$n$ times }}(p).=p.$

---

Obviously, a **fixed point** of $f$ is a periodic point of $f$ (with period $1$), so 
$f(0)=0$ is the only fixed point of $f(x) \implies 0$  is periodic,
I'm not sure how to prove (or disprove) that is unique. 
Is it enough to show that
$$\big\{ x\in(-1,1): \lim_n f^n(x) = 0  \big\} = (-1,1)?$$
Thank you.

Comment: Use $\left| {\sin x} \right| < \left| x \right|$  for $x\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose by contradiction that there exists a non-zero periodic point $x$ of $f$, i.e., $f^p(x)=x$ for some $p\in \mathbb{N}$. Assuming Gary's hint as a fact, then $|\sin^p(x)|=|\sin(\sin^{p-1}(x))|<|\sin^{p-1}(x)|<\ldots <|\sin(x)|<|x|$. Then $|x|<|x|$ contradiction.